# How to redirect a wordpress page to a section of an existing page?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I know there are ways to URL-redirect a Wordpress page to another page via PHP and that you can use HTML to link to a section of a page...but how can I redirect to a section page?

For example, on my home page I have different sections, services and projects. In the main navigation I have a services link. How can I make that open the homepage but just on the homepage.

Comment: Do you mean, if 'Service 1' is half way down the page, when you click on 'Service 1' in your menu you load the homepage but half way down?

Comment: kind of...If 'Services' is on the same page as the homepage, when I click on 'Services' in my menu I want to load the homepage but where services is located (and the same for projects)

Comment: Ok well then if you make an anchor above this header - like `<a id="Services"></a>` giving it an id you wish to use then in your menu you would have a link to `<a href='yourwebsite.com/#services' >Services</a>` you can then do this for any wordpress page eg : `yourwebsite.com/page-1#anchor-link` - so long as you actually have an anchor in your page to link it to, it should load the page at the anchor point - though this can be a little awkward on very short pages.

Comment: This didn't work. When I tried to add the page-1#services in the custom url settings on the services page the hashtag disappears when i confirm. It also then renames all my services urls with page-1 included

Comment: Take a look at my answer. It sounds like you were amending the permalink under the title?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so just tested this on my local wp install.

On the page you want to load part way down add the anchor you require eg:

```
<a id="Services"></a>
```

Then in wordpress > appearance > menus, select your menu. Then on the left hand side, click on 'Links'

Add the full URL of your page eg:

> http://mywebsite.com/home/

Add to this the '#Services' tag to make it look like:

> http://mywebsite.com/home/#Services

Then add it to your menu and save.

You should then be able to click on that button on your menu and the page will drop to the anchor tag when clicked. If you're having trouble with the poundsign/hashtag (#) then you might want to check for conflicting issues in plugins / your functions file - and even wordpress.org uses them on their own site.

Comment: Thats the one, thanks. Problem now is that when Services loads its jerked out of the way due to a revolution slider that takes a bit of time to load and sits at the top of the page. Is there Anyway I can hold it at services?

Comment: I can't say without seeing it for sure but look into page speeds as it sounds like you are loading to the correct place but your slider loads last, do you have any settings to go with your slider you can look into?

Comment: I think its the opposite...i think the slider loads to slow. Minimal settings with the slider. but thanks again.

Comment: I said loads last not loads fast :) but good luck with it anyway